# display top 10 dynamic records in two column(Each 5 records)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm using primefaces 5.2 and jsf. I'm using data-table for displaying top ten failed TC's and those count. Records are dynamic values and fetching from DB, its working fine. But i want display the 10 records in two columns of each 5 records.
For Example :
`TC NAME     COUNT
    TC01_Test     35      TC06_Test     15
    TC02_Test     23      TC07_Test     13
    TC03_Test     20      TC08_Test     10
    TC04_Test     18      TC08_Test     9
    TC05_Test     17      TC10_Test     5`

I want display my records like above mentioned example. How can i achieve this?
XHTML:

```
<div class="DTHeadertwo" >
                        <p:dataTable var="failedTCs" value="#{reportsExeProgressBean.topTenFailedTcs}" >
                            <p:column headerText="TC Name">        
                                <h:outputText style="font-size: 12px;" value="#{failedTCs.testCaseName}" />    
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Failed Count">        
                                <h:outputText style="font-size: 20px;" value="#{failedTCs.failedCount}" />    
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use DataTable in that way

better consider using dataGrid but even with that your list become like this:

```
TC01_Test     35      TC02_Test     15
TC03_Test     23      TC04_Test     13
TC05_Test     20      TC06_Test     10
TC07_Test     18      TC08_Test     9
TC09_Test     17      TC10_Test     5
```

code example:

```
<p:dataGrid var="failedTCs" value="#{reportsExeProgressBean.topTenFailedTcs}" columns="2" layout="grid"
    rows="10" >
    <p:panel style="text-align:center">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%">
           <h:outputText style="font-size: 12px;" value="#{failedTCs.testCaseName}" />
        <h:outputText style="font-size: 20px;" value="#{failedTCs.failedCount}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>
```